# Align MpAndroidChart Bar graph on bottom without XAxis

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using bar graph from `MpAndroidCahrt` on android app.

The problem is bars on graph doesn't align on the bottom.

It has a slight `padding` between bars and bottom side.

I'm not using `XAxis` and `YAxis` either.

**Is there are some solutions?**

Below is my code.

```
chart.data = barData
    chart.barData.barWidth = 0.5f
    chart.setFitBars(true)
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false)
    chart.setPinchZoom(false)
    chart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
    chart.xAxis.isEnabled = false
    chart.axisLeft.removeAllLimitLines()
    chart.axisLeft.addLimitLine(limitLine)
    chart.axisLeft.isEnabled = false
    chart.isDoubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
    chart.description.isEnabled = false
    chart.legend.isEnabled = false
    chart.invalidate()
```

I added screenshot for more information.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Add screenshot of the current state and mention what do you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding can be removed by using

```
chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
xAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
yAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
```

In version 3.0.2 method setAxisMinValue is **deprecated**
so then you can use

```
xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
yAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
```